# Disable the add icon when there is single row of data in the mat-table Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a table inside a card where I have give an add icon to add the details using reactive forms. According to the use case, the user is allowed to add the details only once, later the user can update it or delete it. I want to disable the add icon once there is single row data in the table and enable it again when the user deletes that single row of data. How can I do that?

```
<div class="col">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="col mb-4">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header text-center d-flex">
                  <h2 class="flex-grow-1"><b>Contact Details</b></h2>
                  <a
                    routerLink="/employee/addEmployeeContact"
                    [queryParams]="{ employeeId: employeeDetail.id }"
                    matTooltip="Add Employee Contact Details"
                    ><img
                      width="30"
                      height="30"
                      src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/add--v1.png"
                      alt="create-new--v6"
                  /></a>
                </div>

                <div style="overflow: auto">
                  <table matSort mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
                    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
                          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition"->

                    <!-- Position Column -->

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="workEmailId">
                      <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        Work Email
                      </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        {{ element.workEmailId }}
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="personalEmailId">
                      <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        Personal Email
                      </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        {{ element.personalEmailId }}
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="primaryMobileNo">
                      <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        Primary Mobile No.
                      </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        {{ element.primaryMobileNo }}
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="secondaryMobileNo">
                      <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        Secondary Mobile No.
                      </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        {{ element.secondaryMobileNo }}
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="workPhoneNo">
                      <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        Work Phone No.
                      </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        {{ element.workPhoneNo }}
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="extensionNo">
                      <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        Extension No.
                      </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        {{ element.extensionNo }}
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
                      <th mat-sort-header mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        Status
                      </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        {{ element.status ? "Active" : "Not Active" }}
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="text-center">
                        Actions
                      </th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <div
                          style="
                            display: flex;
                            gap: 10px;
                            justify-content: center;
                          "
                        >
                          <mat-icon
                            routerLink="/employee/updateEmployeeContact"
                            [queryParams]="{
                              employeeId: element.employeeId,
                              employeeContactId: element.id
                            }"
                            class="edit-icon"
                            matTooltip="Update Employee Contact"
                            >edit</mat-icon
                          >

                          <mat-icon
                            (click)="deleteEmployeeContact(element.id)"
                            class="delete-icon"
                            matTooltip="Delete Employee Contact"
                            >delete</mat-icon
                          >
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumn"></tr>
                    <tr
                      mat-row
                      *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumn"
                    ></tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I read it somewhere that I can do that using *ngIf but I am not able to implement it. please Help.

get data -

```
getEmployeeContact = () => {
    this.empData
      .getEmployeeContact(
        `api/Employee/EmployeeContactDetailListByEmployeeId?EmployeeId=${this.employeeId}`
      )
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log('Emp Contact Data', data);
        this.dataSource.data = data;
        this.refreshAddEmployeeContactBtn();
      });
  };
```

Delete Data

```
deleteEmployeeContact = (id: any) => {
    this.dialogService
      .openConfirmDialog(
        'Delete Branch Contact',
        'Are you sure you want to delete this Employee Contact',
        'Delete',
        'Cancel'
      )
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe((res) => {
        if (res) {
          this.empData
            .deleteEmployeeContact(
              `api/Employee/DeleteEmployeeContactDetail?GuidEmployeeContactDetailsId=${id}`
            )
            .subscribe(() => {
              console.log('deleted');
              this.getEmployeeContact();
            });
        }
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `[ngClass]` to control the Add button to be enabled/disabled with CSS.

```
<a
    routerLink="/employee/addEmployeeContact"
    [queryParams]="{ employeeId: employeeDetail.id }"
    matTooltip="Add Employee Contact Details"
    [ngClass]="{ 'disabled': !enableAddEmployeeBtn }"
    ><img
      width="30"
      height="30"
      src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/add--v1.png"
      alt="create-new--v6"
  /></a>
```

```
a.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

In my use case, I would declare an `enableAddEmployeeBtn` to check whether the data source contains any record or not. If the data source is empty, it would store the value as `true`.

```
enableAddEmployeeBtn = false;

refreshAddEmployeeBtn() {
  this.enableAddEmployeeBtn = this.dataSource.data.length == 0;
}
```

When you initialize the data source with data, you should call the `refreshAddEmployeeBtn` method above.

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(data);
this.refreshAddEmployeeBtn();
```

In your `deleteEmployeeContact` function, when your Observable to remove the employee contact is returned, you should refresh/clear the data source and call the `refreshAddEmployeeBtn` method.

```
deleteEmployeeContact(id: number) {
  /* Replace observable with your observable to remove employee contact */
  of(true)
    .subscribe({
      next: (isDeleted: boolean) => {
        if (isDeleted) {
          this.dataSource.data = []; // Clear dataSource
          // Or refresh the dataSource

          this.refreshAddEmployeeBtn();
        }
      },
    });
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ejpwa9?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Hey Yong, thanks for the reply but I'm not able understand the implementation of the deleteEmployeeContact function.
I have updated the question with the delete function that I have used. Please help me with the implementation. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Hi, what is your `getEmployeeContact` implementation? Is it get the data from API and bind the data into data source?

Comment: If yes, so what you should do is to make sure that when the datasource is bonded with data, the `showAddEmployeeBtn` variable should be updated accordingly: `this.showAddEmployeeBtn = this.dataSource.data.length == 0;`

Comment: Yes, I am calling api to get data. I have updated the question again for your reference.

Comment: Hi @CryAndCode, I had revise my answer, the previous demo I done is used to show/hide the button, what you want is to show the button, and enable/disable it.

Comment: Hey Yong, so what I want is that when the table has no records, the add icon will be enabled. And when I add data to the table using a form, the add icon should get disabled. And if I delete that data using delete method, the add icon will get enabled again.
My use case is that user can create only one row of data and not more than that. So the add icon will be enable when there is no data in the table, disabled when there is one row of data and enabled again when user delete that row of data.

Comment: Hi, have you clicked the demo link in my answer and tested it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256189/discussion-between-cryandcode-and-yong-shun).